# Локализация datepicker-а

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

Есть код от https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range
Я в него добавил настройки для русского языка $.datepicker.setDefaults, но календарь перестал работать (исчез выпадающий список).

Что я сделал не так?
Вот код:

```
<?php
function datepicker_js(){
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

        $( function() {
        //Сменим язык календаря на русский
            $.datepicker.setDefaults(
                {
                closeText: 'Закрыть',
                prevText: '',
                currentText: 'Сегодня',
                monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь',
                    'Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн',
                    'Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
                dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
                dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
                weekHeader: 'Не',
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: ''
            };
            //Добавим код календаря
            var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
                from = $( "#ps_second_input_from" )
                    .datepicker({
                        defaultDate: "+1w",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 1
                    })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                        to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
                    }),
                to = $( "#ps_second_input_to" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1
                })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
                    });

            function getDate( element ) {
                var date;
                try {
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
                } catch( error ) {
                    date = null;
                }

                return date;
            }
        } );
    </script>

    <?php

}
```

Comment: Действительно, просмотрел синтаксическую ошибку.
Теперь проблема в том, что календарь перевёлся, но теперь не работает date range - то есть в первом инпуте я выбираю дату, а во втором должен выставиться minDate, что взят из первого, а так не работает)

Comment: а разве он до этого работал? data range ?

Comment: я вставил в ответ новый пример, посмотрите

Comment: Нашёл ошибку)
у меня конфликт получился в таких строках:
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
и
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю вот что вам нужно, подгрузите фаил как есть:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-ru.js

Answer (score 2):

а вот так пробовали?

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
 dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
 minDate: new Date($('#hiddendelivdate').val()),
 monthNames : ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
 dayNamesMin : ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас синтаксическая ошибка, в вашем примере

```
showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: ''
            };
            //Добавим код календаря
```

вы забыли вставить закрывающую скобку `});`  должно быть так:

```
 showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: ''
                });
                //Добавим код календаря
```

При работе с JS кодом всегда следите за ошибками в консоле.
Ваш код можно оптимизировать, попробуйте так:

```
var dateToday = new Date(); 
    $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
                    closeText: 'Закрыть',
                    prevText: 'Пред',
                    nextText: 'След',
                    currentText: 'Сегодня',
                    monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь',
                    'Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн',
                    'Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
                    dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
                    dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
                    weekHeader: 'Нед',
                    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                    firstDay: 1,
                    isRTL: false,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: ''};
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);  

            $('#ps_second_input_from').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
            maxDate: dateToday,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#ps_second_input_to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            },
                });



            $('#ps_second_input_to').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
            maxDate: dateToday,
            minDate: minDate,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#ps_second_input_from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",  selectedDate );
            },
                });
```

Comment: Действительно, просмотрел. Спасибо!)
Теперь проблема в том, что календарь перевёлся, но теперь не работает date range - то есть в первом инпуте я выбираю дату, а во втором должен выставиться minDate, что взят из первого, а так не работает)